# How to programmatically install wampapache64

Tags: apache, wamp, mod-wsgi, wampserver, server-side

I am trying to host my Django project with WAMPServer.

I have edited a couple of WAMPServer file, say `https.conf` for adding `mod_wsgi` configurations, python home path, also I have changed the listen port to 8000.

So i have decided to keep this edited wamp64 folder and copy this to C: drive instead of installing the WAMPServer( which would give me unedited wamp folder).

I am starting wampmanager.exe from a shell script after copying the edited wamp folder.

But this requires me to go to `wampmanager->apache->install` to install wampapache64.

Can I do this in my shell script?

Is there any command to install wampapache64 manually?

Or a better way to edit wamp folder files after a fresh installation?

Thank you

Comment: For now I am installing the wamp server and replacing the edited files

Comment: Apache in WAMPServer is just Apache! See [Running Apache as a Service](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html) `httpd.exe -k install -n "wampapache64"`

Comment: _Small Note_ Changing the Listen Port to 8000 only makes you life more complicated. Why did you do that

Comment: I already have my django server hosted on linux with 8000 port. I am extending this to windows now. frontend service will be expecting django server running on 8000 port. Using port 80 will not work for me.